# Why atmospheric pressure on a liquid and not on a solid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure, fluid-statics

An open cylindrical container (radius = 0.5 m)  has 100 kg of water.

a) Find the water pressure at the bottom of the container.
b) Find the pressure exerted by the container on the floor (ignore the mass of the container)

What confuses me, in  a) We simply use p = p0  + ρgh

then in b) p = F/A  =  ρgh     then we already had a larger pressure in a) and now, in b) the pressure is much smaller ( but the water inside the container, at the bottom yields a much larger pressure??)

---

Can someone enligthen me please?  I feel I'm missing a key concept here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should have been explicitly mentioned in part (b) that the value of excess pressure is being asked. By excess pressure, I mean the difference between the pressure on the ground below the container and the pressure on the ground elsewhere. This way, the answer $\rho g h$ is justified.